# Why observer stay alive after a view controller is deinitialized and causes SIGABRT or EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, key-value-observing

I have a simple application with two view controllers, the first one with a button to show the second one which plays a video from an URL with an AVPlayerViewController and AVPlayer. In the viewDidAppear() of the second view controller I initialize the AVPlayerViewController, configure the AVPlayer and add an observer to the AVPlayer to detect when the video start playing.

If I dismiss manually the second view controller before the video has started (it has to be dismissed rapidly, using a slow Internet connection can help to do this) I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS because it seems that observeValue() get called but the variable accessed in this method (here a container view) does not existing anymore.

I have to remove the observer in deinit to solve this issue.
When I try to remove it in other places like viewWillDisappear() sometimes the observer is not even added so I get a SIGABRT (strange because I add it in viewDidAppear()) when removing:

```
'Cannot remove an observer <App.SecondViewController 0x101805600> for the key path "status" from <AVPlayer 0x1c801a0b0> because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

**Someone know why?**

And the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412787-addobserver) also says:

> Neither the object receiving this message, nor observer, are retained.

**Why exactly do I need to remove the observer in deinit? In other words, why the observer stays alive after deinit in my case?**

Here is the code for the second view controller (the first one only have a UIButton for the show segue and is embedded in a NavigationController):

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    var player: AVPlayer!

    deinit {
        //player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let url = URL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4")

        // Create the player and player view controller.
        player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player

        // Add observer to detect when the video start playing.
        player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

        // Add the player controller in the container view.
        self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)
        self.containerView.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
        playerViewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        playerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        player.play()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        //player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        print("SndVC - Memory Warning")
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "status" {
            // Perform a task on the container view.
            self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: deinit called ????

Comment: Yes, I call deinit to solve the issue, however I would like to know why I need to remove the observer in deinit since the Apple documentation says that since iOS 9 is it automatically un-registered and only need to be un-registered when it is a block based observer.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say why it's crashing without actually debugging the app. But I would pair `addObserver` / `removeObserver` either in `viewWillAppear` / `viewDidDisappear` *or* `init` and `dealloc`.

(I generally wouldn't put any KVO code in `viewDidLoad` because it has no partner callback from `UIKit`)

PS: you're also missing the call to `super.viewDidAppear()`

Comment: The only debugging I was able to do with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is using Zombie objects and I get: [App.SecondViewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10a5012a0. The KVO code is in viewDidAppear() it was a mistake in the question, do you still think it is a bad idea to use it here? I wasn't able to find another way to observe the AVPlayer. By the way, thank you to point out my mistake with viewDidAppear().